# How do I pass both latitude and longitude coordinates on button press and drop a pin on next map view?

Tags: xcode, nsstring, latitude-longitude, cllocation

I feel like I'm getting close if someone can just help me on the last stretch!

Currently I have the following:

```
{
   CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
   location.latitude = (double) 44.4758;
   location.longitude = (double) -73.2125;

   str = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.longitude] stringValue];

   viewController.stringToDisplay = str;
}
```

Now, this is passing the longitude value, but it won't of course let me include the latitude. What can I write to include both in the same line?

Thank you!

Comment: Greg: Mark your answer as the accepted solution and put your second request in its own separate question. That'll get it noticed better. If you already asked it elsewhere, edit and remove. Then we can remove this comment too. Good housekeeping gets you more answers. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DID IT!! So happy. I pass different coordinates from a previous view based on the button pressed and am pinning those coordinates on the next view with IF statements. This is no doubt a simple thing for a programming guru, but I have no experience so I'm happy :)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{
  CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
  NSLog(@"self.stringToDisplay = %@", self.stringToDisplay);

  if ([self.stringToDisplay isEqualToString: @"44.48, -73.21"])
  {
    location.latitude = (double) 44.4758;
    location.longitude = (double) -73.2125;

    MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Burlington, VT" andCoordinate:location];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
  }

  if ([self.stringToDisplay isEqualToString: @"51.50, -0.14"])
  {
    location.latitude = (double) 51.5010;
    location.longitude = (double) -0.1425;

    MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Buckingham Palace" andCoordinate:location];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
 str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", location.latitude, location.longitude];
```

or more human-readable:

```
 str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f, %.2f", location.latitude, location.longitude];
```